# Spark SaveAsTable takes lot of time

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to perform few join on different hive table using Spark and trying to save the final table into hive as well.

The problem is SaveAsTable stage takes almost `12 minutes`. Table has `16 million row`.

There are two executors and total 64 tasks are created. The problem is all the task   processes around **17 MB** however the last task processes **250 MB of data.**

I tried to do repartition to 264, however it creates the new stage after above stage. which is weird.

[image: Please check the picture here]

Comment: Can you share your source?

Comment: it sounds like you have a skew join, take a look at this https://medium.com/simpl-under-the-hood/spark-protip-joining-on-skewed-dataframes-7bfa610be704

Comment: @BiRico you are right, I have skew join.